# Setting up Node App along with nginx server

Tags: linux, nginx, proxy, node.js

I am trying to set up a new node all along with my previous PHP app.

#### Scenario

- The php app runs on `www.xyz.com`. It is served using nginx.
- The node app is served via NodeJs server on port 8142.

I want to server the NodeJs app at the link
`www.xyz.com/nodeApp`

#### What I tried

My approach was to proxy all the request made on `www.xyz/nodeApp` to the port 8142, where the node server will pick up.

I added the following proxy conf to the nginx file of `www.xyz.com`.

```
location ~ ^/nodeApp(.*)$ {
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_pass_request_body on;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8142$1$is_args$args;
   proxy_buffering off;
}
```

#### Result

On hitting the `www.xyz.com/nodeApp/`, everything works. Node server picks up the request and serves the `css` and `js` files at link `www.xyz.com/nodeApp/app.js` etc.

#### But (without the trailing slash)

On hitting the `www.xyz.com/nodeApp`, it doesn't work. 
Node server picks up the request and serves the `html` page correctly but the `css` and `js` files are served at link `www.xyz.com/app.js` etc. So the app breaks.

Where I am wrong ?

#### My node server file

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8142;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simplify config:

```
location /nodeApp/ {
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8142/;
   proxy_buffering off;
}
```

In this case nginx will take care of trailing slash. See http://nginx.org/r/location

> If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash character, and requests are processed by one of `proxy_pass`, [...], then the special processing is performed. In response to a request with URI equal to this string, but **without the trailing slash**, a permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with the slash appended.

Also, there is no need for variables in `proxy_pass`. Nginx will replace prefix `/nodeApp/` with `/` and append query strings automatically.